# Why won't padding-left in select box options show in Chrome but works in FF?

Tags: css, google-chrome, padding, drop-down-menu

I added a css class to options in a select dropdown box for indention,

```
<select id="users" name="users">
    <option value="[1,2,3]">Devs team</option>
    <option value="1" class="member">user1</option>
    <option value="2" class="member">user2</option>
    <option value="3" class="member">user3</option>
</select>
```

It shows correctly on Firefox but not on Chrome. :(

Hope you guys could help me with this little problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. Sadly chrome doesn't support giving styles to option.

Comment: I think you meant to say that Chrome has limited support for `<option>` styles, but some are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reliably style select and option elements.  Browsers typically like to stick to the OS defaults for these elements.

If you are looking to pad .member because they are children of the Devs Team, you may want to look at the OPTGROUP tag:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: Please [don't link w3schools](http://w3fools.com). Use [MDN instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/optgroup) :)

Comment: I always see people flaming W3Schools but in this case they have more information that the link you pointed to. Please tell me what content on the w3schools link Skylar posted is inaccurate

Comment: Hi I'm not keen on using optgroup in this case. I think optgroup doesn't have a value attribute?

Comment: @cancelledout  `<optgroup>` has a label attribute which is the actual text you see.  The `<optgroup>` is not meant to be selected.  Only the options within the `<optgroup>` are submitted with the form.